# when and where to show ads in android application

Tags: android, android-activity, integration, admob, ads

I already integrated admob and madvertise to my apps but revenues are pretty low although the downloads and installs are ok/high. one of my apps is a little converter tool, the other is a small casual game.

now i wonder what is the best way to show and place ads in my app.

1. I try to show an ad in the onStart method and destroy it in the onStop method as the Activity Lifecycle says in onStart the activity becomes visible to the user. is this ok or will it increase the total number of requests/impressions and so decrease my CTR?
2. Should I show ads in activities which are only viewed for a short time e.g. main menu-activity, the level choose-activity or the profile-activity? Or is it better to just show ads in the game-activity as this is viewed for a longer time?
3. are there other certain rules/guidelines for when/when not show an ad in an activity?

thanks in advance

Comment: I am also the author of two applications on the market. My best experience so far: Create free apps, with no ads at all. When you have a big base of users (>100K) create an element with some added value. Offer this added value as something to buy in the app, or in a paid verison of the app. Anyway, if you find any other opinions, listen to the others, since I have not been able to make a significant amount of money so far.

Comment: thanks so far. i shoud mention i have a free version (~70000 downloads) and a paid version (~400 downloads) of the tool app in the market. the paid version makes about half of the money the free version makes. as there are many similar apps in the market on a competitive basis i dont think it's good to go the way you suggested cause many user might switch to another app offering the same functions totally for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to show ads on the bottom part of your screen in all the activities, but give the user a way to  hide them for some of the screens (an x mark or maybe from menu).
Don't force the user to see an add or to be forced to close it every time. Adds should be hints not a pain for users :)

Good luck,
Arkde

Comment: The authors of Wordfeud should read this post. That app is a fscking pain in the backbone regarding forced ads.

Comment: thanks. actually the user is not forced to closed the ad every time, i placed all the ads at the bottom of the screen so the user can interact with the app and ignore the ad. but this is still an interesting suggestion. do you have any experience with this approach? i never saw an app that let the user disable ads so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: You can set the visibility for views to `View.GONE` or `View.INVISIBLE`. Place that in a event (Motion event for instance) and you can hide it. Or hide your views on click event for an item in the menu :)

Comment: ok, sorry this was misleading. i'm aware of how to do this technically, i wanted to know if this is a good solution for increasing the revenue. does this increase your CTR as only users who are interested in ads still watch ads or what? :)

Comment: Well adds on all pages on bottom of the screen may increase your revenue, since they can be seen often (it's not a rule). But first of all you have to be aware that you shouldn't force users to do anything, so giving them control over the add may be a nice user experience, and you might get more downloads, and more chances to increase your revenue. As @bos said in the first comment, don't transform your app in a pain in the backbone :)

Comment: i really appreciate your answers but i dont see that giving the user the ability to disable ads will increase my revenue. actually i never had a user who complained about the ads and i would say that my app shows ads on a quite normal level like most apps with ads do. besides that, the number of downloads would have to increase extraordinary to give this approach a noticeable effect.

Comment: The disable of the add was just a sugestion :)